# difference between two answers from Integral calculator

Tags: integration

I often use this [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) to compute integrals. So there is always two answers:

1. "MANUALLY" COMPUTED ANTIDERIVATIVE
2. ANTIDERIVATIVE COMPUTED BY MAXIMA:

For eg,
if I want to do $\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax}}{x^2} dx$ :

1. "MANUALLY" COMPUTED ANTIDERIVATIVE gives: $$\mathrm{i}a\operatorname{Ei}\left(\mathrm{i}ax\right)-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax}}{x}$$
2. ANTIDERIVATIVE COMPUTED BY MAXIMA gives: $$\mathrm{i}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-1,-\mathrm{i}ax\right)a$$

What is the difference between both answers?

Comment: The 1st uses the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral the 2nd uses the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: An antiderivative of a function $f(x)$ is a function whose derivative is equal to $f(x)$. That is, if $F′(x)=f(x)$, then $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. An indefinite integral is an integral written without terminals; it simply asks to find a general antiderivative of the integrand. Maxima can compute indefinite integrals of many functions. [More can be found here.](https://blogs.ubc.ca/moiz12/2017/01/25/integral-vs-antiderivative/)

Comment: i guess integration/antiderivative may have one or more correct answers

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between $\mathrm{i}a\operatorname{Ei}\left(\mathrm{i}ax\right)-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax}}{x}$ and$\mathrm{i}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-1,-\mathrm{i}ax\right)a$, or the difference between the two answers provided by Integral Calculator in general?

Comment: Derivative of $i a \Gamma (-1,-i a x)$ is $\frac{e^{i a x}}{x^2}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I was expecting an answer similar to what Laufen said. @Kyky I also wanted to know how can I equate  $\mathrm{i}a\operatorname{Ei}\left(\mathrm{i}ax\right)-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}ax}}{x}$ and $\mathrm{i}\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(-1,-\mathrm{i}ax\right)a$